# Part of the CSS only applying to one of multiple elements with the same classname

Tags: html, css

I am just working on a simple little layout and I have run into a funny CSS issue.

I have two buttons both with the class of 'button', and in my css I have

```
.button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #888;
    border: solid 1px #555;
    padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button:hover {
    color: #eee;    
    background-color: #999;
    border: solid 1px #777;
}
```

On the second button all of the css rules are applied, however for the first button the cursor never is applied, also the entire hover block is never hit.

[Here is an example of what i'm talking about](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/VdmS9/1/)

Comment: I was testing in FireFox 6.0, sorry should have mentioned that. however if you have read below.. fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Found my issue! Sorry everyone.

For anyone who cares.... 
I had applied a css rule to the header text on the page that was making it overlay the button on the left, and therefore blocking the cursor from 'hovering'

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/VdmS9/2/

Answer (score 0):

The styles gets applied correctly, only the button is covered by `h3` element. Try adding `position:relative; z-index:1;`
I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VdmS9/3/).

Comment: Thanks, I had noticed that myself :) I can just remove the position and top rules from that class, they are not needed. I had initially had them there before I changed how my top and bottom bars would be layed out.